# MySQL SUM() with JOIN and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, join, sum, limit

The concerned schema and query is on SQL fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/312d3/16

The JOIN query below gets the result that I want.

```
SELECT p.*, payer.username as payer_username, payee.username as
payee_username FROM (`payments_history` p)  JOIN (SELECT * FROM users)
AS payer ON `payer`.`user_id` = `p`.`payer_id`  JOIN (SELECT * FROM
users) AS payee ON `payee`.`user_id` = `p`.`payee_id`  ORDER BY
`p`.`created_timestamp`;
```

Doing a sum() on the "p.amount" column for all the rows works fine too.

```
SELECT SUM(p.amount)  FROM (`payments_history` p)  JOIN (SELECT * FROM
users) AS payer ON `payer`.`user_id` = `p`.`payer_id`  JOIN (SELECT *
FROM users) AS payee ON `payee`.`user_id` = `p`.`payee_id`  ORDER BY
`p`.`created_timestamp`;
```

But doing a sum() on the same column for the rows on each page (offset,limit) returns an empty result (I would like to have the total of the "amount" column for the rows on each page).

```
SELECT SUM(p.amount)  FROM (`payments_history` p)  JOIN (SELECT * FROM
users) AS payer ON `payer`.`user_id` = `p`.`payer_id`  JOIN (SELECT *
FROM users) AS payee ON `payee`.`user_id` = `p`.`payee_id`  ORDER BY
`p`.`created_timestamp` limit 0,2;
```

Also in the sum() query, when the offset starts from anything greater than 0 (try LIMIT 2,2), it returns an empty result.

What am I doing wrong?.
Thank you.

Comment: The query is working correctly.  Can you describe what you want your query to do?

Comment: The SUM() of query when used with LIMIT clause is not working correctly. For instance, for "LIMIT 0,1"  is not it supposed to give the sum of just that one row?. It instead gives the sum of all the rows.

Comment: Also you can see with the LIMIT clause when the offset starts from anything greater than 0 (try "LIMIT 1,1")  it returns an empty result.

Comment: There will only be one row because you are SELECTing just the sum.

Comment: @James I am aware of that. The problem here is, in one case (try LIMIT 0,1) it gives the sum of all the rows instead of just that one row. In another case (try LIMIT 1,1) it returns empty result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT SUM(l.amount)  FROM (
  SELECT p.amount FROM payments_history p
  INNER JOIN users payer ON payer.user_id=p.payer_id
  INNER JOIN users payee ON payee.user_id=p.payee_id
  ORDER BY p.created_timestamp
  LIMIT 0,10
) l
```

I'm not sure if you plan to add other fields to the query, or have further conditions in a WHERE clause, but having those joins in there doesn't seem all that useful right now.

Comment: That works,thank you!. And yes I got use conditions in the WHERE clause over the payer/payee columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is just a little vague. What will be on the page that you want to have sums on? Is it a report for the specific user? If so, then you can just add a WHERE clause to your query to limit the sum to just that user. Something like:

```
SELECT SUM(p.amount)  
FROM (`payments_history` p)  
JOIN (SELECT * FROM users) AS payer ON `payer`.`user_id` = `p`.`payer_id`  
JOIN (SELECT * FROM users) AS payee ON `payee`.`user_id` = `p`.`payee_id`
WHERE payer.user_id = [the user id] 
ORDER BY `p`.`created_timestamp`;
```

If that's not what you want, then you may want to clarify the question a little bit. It's unclear.

**Question:**
Are you trying to get the sum of just one row? (your answer in the comments makes it seem that way) If so, that's just the value in the amount. You can't sum a single value.

Comment: Right,that SUM() query on a single row could be confusing(I had just 2 rows on the sql fiddle). I edited the question.  Thank you.